# Postgres 9.4 Foreign Data wrapper "FDW" is unable to send serial data type between insertion from different ends

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper

I have a simple 2 CentOS servers configurations using both postgres-9.4 to simulate the FDW scenario in Postgres-9.4.

I used fdw to link a simple table with a another database on another server, reading worked perfectly from both ends,the issue was with the serial primary key, it was not in sync; in other words, If I inserted from the original  table, after I inserted from the foreign table, it doesn't sync the count. and vise versa.

Comment: `SERIAL` isn't a real type. It's just a syntactic shortcut for [a bunch of other commands](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL). The actual column type is `INTEGER`; try using that in your foreign table instead.

Comment: @NickBarnes You're right, I did an easy work around I'll answer my question shortly

Comment: Follow this: <https://paquier.xyz/postgresql-2/global-sequences-with-postgres_fdw-and-postgres-core/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment I got from Nick Barnes, yes I do need to keep up the counter on both sides in sync, so I made a Function that every time Queries the Actual Database for the latest index, so that is always inserts to the correct record.
I am still not sure if this is going to survive, but I'll make it work production really soon.

I blogged about it [here](http://manegm.com/synced-sequences-with-postgres_fdw/) with a table example.

Comment: 404 Not Found :-(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and tried it like Negma suggested in his blog. This solution only works in case you insert only one row. In case you insert more rows in the same transaction, `select max(id)` will always return the same id and you will get not unique ids.

I have solved this by changing the type of the id from serial/integer to uuid. Then you can do the same as Negma suggested but with gen_random_uuid() from the pgcrypto EXTENSION.

So at the foreign server I did:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN columnname SET DEFAULT gen_random_uuid();
```

And the same for the foreign table.